# How can I open a modal window after successful AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am using a [modal window plugin](http://joaopereirawd.github.io/animatedModal.js/) for user signup and login pages. After a successful AJAX call how can I open it automatically? I.e. without clicking or submission it should be opened automatically after a successful AJAX call. Please advise on this.

Comment: open it on doc ready if jquery is used or learn about `DOMContentLoaded` event.

Comment: Invoke the popup opening function just after the success of ajax function

Comment: yes how to invoke the popup . for example i need like $("#completeactionmodle").modal('open'). but i cant use the above mentioned animated modal js

Comment: $("#demo01").animatedModal(); is given at documentation . If your libraries are included properly you can invoke this in callback function.. It would be nice if you can share working fiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ravybbhe/

Answer (score 0):

```
try to define in call back of success field in ajax
```

```
   $.ajax({
         url: "demo_test.txt", 
         success: function(result){
                $('#my-modal').modal();
         },
         error: function(){
                console.log("Something went wrong");  
         }
    });
```

Comment: them, use  $("#my-modal").animatedModal();

Comment: tried with the above function not working. it will work only when call it a href

Comment: then instead of model() use animatedModal() like this $("#demo01").animatedModal()

Comment: actually if you look inot animatedmodal.js it will work only if you call it in <a href="#demo1">demo1</a> then only it will work

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function(result){
   $("yourmodel").animatedModal(); 
}
```

Comment: tried with the above function not working. it will work only when call it a href

Comment: And if you trigger('click') on the button that open the modal?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#yourmodalidgoeshere").animatedModal(); 
//triggers opening of Modal.
$("#yourmodalidgoeshere").click();
```

The click() helps to trigger the modal. It worked for me. It didn't try with ajax call. I wanted to load the modal on click of an element . Inside the javascript function I had used the above lines and it worked well.